# Typescript with Express: Received a ts(7053) error message when trying to access data from req.body

Tags: typescript, express

I am trying to write an express application with Typescript. The problem is that I having trouble assigning the data property from req.body to posts. When I hoover over posts of `posts[id]` in the if statement, I received the message ts(7053). I receive the same message for id as well. Ditto for `const post:postType = posts[postId];`.

Following from the 7053 error, I get a ts(2339) error message on `post.comments.push({id,content})` . Where I can not access the comments property of post even through I have given it a type of postType.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const port = 4002;
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors);

type comment = {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  postid: string;
};

type postType =
  | {
      id: string;
      title: string;
      comments: comment[];
    }
  | {};

const posts: postType = {};

app.get('/post', (req, res) => {});

app.post('/events', (req, res) => {
  const { type, data } = req.body;

  if (type === 'POSTCREATED') {
    const { id, title } = data;
    posts[id] = { id, title, comments: [] };
    // Receiving an error message: **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}
  }
  if (type === 'COMMENTCREATED') {
    const { id, content, postId } = data;

    const post: postType = posts[postId];
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.
    post.
    //Property 'comments' does not exist on type 'postType'. Property 'comments' does not exist on type '{}'
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}.`);
});
```

Obviously, I was expecting no errors. I tried adding an index signature and that didn't worked. But that lead to a different set of problems that made it more complicated. So I reverted the code.

Comment: While giving defination to your posts var do it like this 
`const posts: postType ={} as postType; `

Comment: The message is now "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'postType'."